# Show warning message upon the overlay div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I disabled the entire page using the over-lay div and I want to show an warning message upon this overlay div . Please let me know , how to handle this.
If I add add div after overlay div , it showing hidden. I want have this warning message upon this overlay div.

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

```css
#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$("#overlay").show();
```

Thanks

Comment: show us how you disable the entire page

Comment: Why don't you write your message in overlay div?

Comment: Do you want like https://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/47kna753/ or http://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/kaJSs/219/?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jhv95jpp/)

Added some HTML, made a sibling to the overlay div

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="warning">
I am a warning
</div>
```

applied almost same css on `#warning` except the `z-index`

```
#warning{
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  border:solid 1px red;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

and used `callback` of overlay to `show` warning div

```
 $("#overlay").show(function(){
    $('#warning').show();
});
```